# Use Putty console in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, putty

Is there a way to show console of putty in console of Notepad++ (NppExec)?

I am editing files in remote server in Notepad++ with help of WinSCP. And executing console programs from putty console. As I can use cmd inside NppExec, is there any way to use putty's console inside Notpad++?

Comment: Hi. Could you mark the question as answered, please?

Answer (score 22):

*(Very late answer but it may help people who are looking for an answer)*

What you are looking for is:

1. A plugin to run commands (**NppExec** that I use a lot, or NppConsole)
2. The batch version of putty available on Putty website: [**plink**](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
3. If your remote machine is under a Linux system, a tool to convert from Linux to Windows: [**ansicon**](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads)
4. Copy the executable in some folder and put this folder in your path
5. Restart Notepad++
6. Run the command `ansicon.exe plink.exe -ssh user@location -pw yourpasword` (F6 key for NppExec)

... And that's it!

*PS: Thanks a lot to Svenn for the post on [his blog](http://www.svennd.be/putty-inside-notepad/)*

Comment: This going to open putty from Notepad ++ , no more no less, I believe what opp ment is, to transfer/run scripts from Notepat++ in to putty, or in this case in to plink. without copy paste. for instance as PyNPP plugin does for Python script

Comment: Will it open putty in a new window or run ssh commands from within Notepad++ console?

Comment: It will open in the Notepadd+ console (NppExec console to be precise)

Comment: @Zaza, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18841008/2955790), plus this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000493/2955790),  together allow the user to do two important things: (1)This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39000493/2955790) allows the user to browse the remote code, edit the code, and have those changes on the fly be sent over to the remote machine, and (2)Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18841008/2955790), you can compile that edited-code using the terminal that it opens. Especially nice-to-have, if you are working on remote makefiles.

Answer (score 8):

I know this thread is incredibly dead and i hate to necro, but i felt like this was worth it to share.

You can also download the [Notepad++ Console Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppconsole/) which is (imo) a cleaner solution to using ssh when you have putty installed. It will of course also work as just a command prompt for windows.

When you have this plugin installed you can open up an ssh connection using
`ssh username@destination.com`
which will open up a TTY.

Comment: Is there any way multiple such console windows can be open? 
Thanks

Comment: Hello, where can we find a  x64 NppConsole.dll, iam looking for hours and i can find only x32 bit but my NPP is x64 bit.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a real improvement over the last answers: I have just tried out NppFTP which is available from the plugins list inside NotePad++ (Plugins --> Plugin Manager and select NppFTP).
It does the job, just plain and neat.

Answer (score 2):

You can use plink.exe utility. Just run this utility from command line. Try to find this utility in folder with Putty.